# SQL: Select rows with bigger than max in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table "*TBL1*":

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

Table "*TBL2*":

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

I tried this:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM TBL1 Where a > MAX (tbl2.a);
```

Obviously it didn't work. Ideally the solution would work in sqlite.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Are you sure you described the requirement correctly? Isn't the real use case fo fetch those rows which appear in table1, but don't in table2? This condition with "MAX" looks strange and will not make sense if for example table2 is empty.

Comment: @JonasMetzler No, this is just a simplified example to get the point faster.

Comment: So if the second table is empty, your query will not select any rows. Is this really the intended behaviour?

Comment: @JonasMetzler yes, the 2nd table will never be empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a subquery for that:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM TBL1 Where a > (SELECT MAX(a) FROM tbl2);
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9xHRjgoNfDwaVRV1yaExCW/0).

Comment: And thanks for making the original post prettier!